# Is TextMesh Pro InputField for password secure?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textmeshpro

I'm making a mobile online game with Unity.
Just like other online games, there is a login screen for entering an ID/password with TMP_InputField from TextMesh Pro.
The password input field is covered with asterisks, but the value of the input field
still contains the password string, so what if a hacker or malware takes this data?
Is the input field secure enough?
Or do I need to strengthen security in other ways?

Thanks

Comment: Nope... it is by far safe from security.
You need to encrypt that inputfield., and store it on the seperate server(never in local devices).
Try to take a look at AES 256 encryption method..

Comment: and to add that.. that asteriks input field is just purely for UI purposes.. and it doesnt have any no security method at all.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could mimic WPF apps where [`PasswordBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.passwordbox?view=netframework-4.7.2) was placed in the GUI with [`SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=netframework-4.7.2) as the data structure.  [`SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=netframework-4.7.2) isn't perfect however, it merely shortens the time the decrypted string is accessible in memory (as opposed to a regular `string` which is subject to a unpredictable GC event).

Obviously you can't use WPF controls but you could easily create your own control using whichever Unity UI framework your prefer.

Note that in .NET 5+ (though from a Unity perspective technically doesn't apply) [`SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=net-5.0#remarks) has a [not recommended warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=net-5.0#remarks) whose detail is covered [here](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md).  However the debate over whether it's a good idea to deal with credentials in any app arguably still applies to Unity.

### Alternatives

Generally the best security is when the application does not deal with usernames and passwords<sup>1</sup>.

e.g.

1. Windows Authentication (though kinda pointless for games)
2. Certificates (unheard of in gaming)
3. Rely on an established SSO provider. e.g. **XUser** part of the *Microsoft Game Development Kit for Unity*

Signing into GDK in Unity (sample courtesy of GDK):

```
// Look ma, no need for passwords!
XUserAddOptions options = XUserAddOptions.AddDefaultUserAllowingUI;
SDK.XUserAddAsync(options, AddUserComplete);

private void AddUserComplete(int hresult, XUserHandle userHandle)
{
    if (!Succeeded(hresult, "Sign in."))
    {
        return;
    }

    _userHandle = userHandle;
    CompletePostSignInInitialization();
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> [DE0001: SecureString shouldn't be used](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md)

### See also

- *["Integrating the Microsoft Game Development Kit with your PC Unity game"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/gdk/_content/gc/get-started-with-pc-dev/get-started-with-unity-pc/gdk-unity-end-to-end-guide)*, GDK, Microsoft (complete with a nice Unity tutorial)
- *["Implement player sign in"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/gdk/_content/gc/get-started-for-gdk-playfab-titles/gdk-playfab-player-sign-in-steps)*, GDK, Microsoft